# Real time hive import from MySQL

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I have a requirement where data is getting inserted into MySQL database at a very high rate (30000 - 40000 rows every couple of mins). I need to import this data from MySQL to Hive after doing some processing, e.g. group by, summation. And use the Hive Datastore to run some analytics processes.

I am using Sqoop to handle the import part. AFAIK, Oozie can be used to configure Sqoop imports as scheduled jobs (run say after every 5 mins). But is it possible to configure Sqoop imports on the basis of update/insert in MySQL, say for every insert in table1 in MySQL, sqoop job should run to import the newly inserted data (in append mode for Sqoop), so that data in Hive should be almost real time.